# avoid #NV values with excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have written this piece of code:

```
thisworkbook.Sheets("test_destination").Range("J2:K" & lastrow_orgid).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(diesesworkbook.Sheets("test_source").Range("J2:K" & lastrow_orgid).Value)
```

It does what it is supposed to do but it creates these #NV values. Maybe someone could tell me if there is another way to write this to avoid these #NV values.

[image: source]

[image: destination]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things.

1. Work with objects. This will make your life easier.
2. You are assuming that the returned range will have the same width as the input range and hence you are getting that error.
3. Store the unique values in an array and then output the array to the relevant range.

Here is an example. Amend as applicable.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CriarBotaoLaranja()
    Dim ArOutput As Variant
    Dim wsA As Worksheet
    Dim wsB As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow_orgid As Long
    
    '~~> Change the worksheets as applicable
    Set wsA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test_destination")
    Set wsB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test_source")
    
    '~~> Harcoding this value. change as applicable
    lastrow_orgid = 10
    
    '~~> Get the unique values in an array
    ArOutput = WorksheetFunction.Unique(wsB.Range("J2:K" & lastrow_orgid).Value)
    
    '~~> Output the result to the relevant range
    wsA.Range("J2").Resize(UBound(ArOutput), 2).Value = ArOutput
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! I did declare the objects I just only copied this specific line of code.

Comment: I have a question regarding the array. Is there a way to access a specific column like in python? Something like ArOutput[0] to get the values for org and ArOutput[1]?

Comment: `ArOutput(Row,Column)`. For example `ArOutput(1,1)` and `ArOutput(1,2)`

Comment: I need the whole column 1 and 2 because I need to paste them in switched order. Like "id" and "org" and not anymore like "org" and "id". I hope you understand me. :D

Comment: So let me get this correct. you want the output in reverse? "Id" first and then "org"?

Comment: yes I meant this :D

Comment: Yes that is possible. Create a duplicate array and then loop through the old array and replace value in the new array. `ArOutput(i, 1) = ArTemp(i, 2) : ArOutput(i, 2) = ArTemp(i, 1)`